# can not insert data into the database

Tags: mysql, sql, jdbc

here is the thing

```
ps = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO goods_country(goodsId,goodsCountry) VALUES (?,?)");
ps.setInt(1, this.returnId());
ps.setString(2, goodsCountry);
int exe = ps.executeUpdate();
```

Im sure that `this.returnId()` and `goodsCountry` has value,
when run this code that occur this error

> java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:963)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:896)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:885)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:860)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.checkBounds(PreparedStatement.java:3321)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setInternal(PreparedStatement.java:3306)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setInternal(PreparedStatement.java:3345)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setInt(PreparedStatement.java:3296)
>       at com.backend.model.MoviesBeanBO.inserCountry(MoviesBeanBO.java:67)
>       at com.backend.controller.MovieOnBoard.doPost(MovieOnBoard.java:71)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>       at filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:25)

can't figure it out what happened,
if somebody can help ,I would be very appreciate.  thx!

Comment: Can't see an error in your code. Which version of the jdbc driver are you using? Maybe you could verify if this error occors if you use another driver version

Comment: Try to remove space between values and (?,?)

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove space between values and question mark

```
    ps = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO goods_country(goodsId,goodsCountry) VALUES(?,?)");
    ps.setInt(1, this.returnId());
    ps.setString(2, goodsCountry);
    int exe = ps.executeUpdate();
```

or the driver jar file needs to be checked.